# Skype always shows up as weird number on caller id

Tags: skype

When using Skype, It always shows up as a different number on caller ID.  Sometimes it shows up as a weird number i.e.: 123456789 and sometimes it shows up as a correct number with a random area code.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to [set up your caller ID](http://share.skype.com/sites/business/2008/06/display_your_phone_number_when.html):

> You can use online numbers from
>   Denmark, Estonia, Hong Kong, Japan,
>   Poland, Sweden, United States and the
>   UK. Hopefully we will be adding more
>   countries to the list shortly.
>
> How to set up caller identification:
>
> Caller identification, as we call this
>   feature, is easy to set up. Simply
>   sign in to [your account](https://secure.skype.com/store/settings/cli/settings) and follow the
>   on-screen instructions.
>
> Please note that if you have
>   previously set up your mobile number
>   to show when sending SMS messages you
>   don't need to verify the number again.
>   Just choose to use the same number to
>   show for SkypeOut calls.
>
> You will see a screen similar to this:
>
> [image: Skype screenshot]
>
> In this case you can choose between
>   using your online number or the mobile
>   phone number associated with your
>   Skype account.
>
> If you have not previously associated
>   a mobile number with your Skype
>   account, you will need to verify the
>   mobile number by following the
>   instructions sent to you in an SMS.